# Marshalling nested objects with JAXB - unwrapped

Tags: java, json, jaxb, nested

I've got a very simple problem here, but after using Google for over an hour now, I still cannot find a good solution and it starts to cost too much money..

In my app I use REST as an API, basically only with JSON as payload type, and Enunciate for documentation of the API. As you might know, enunciate will generate an xsd schema from the classes. I am therefore in the situation, that I need to configure all the DTO's for Jackson/JSON handling with the suitable annotations, and also with JAXB annotation to ensure the generated schema is correct and can be parsed with XJC into the correct classes!

Although that is not very difficult to achieve and works flawless in most of the cases, I have a simple but somehow special case, in which it completely fails.

Assuming the following classes:

```js
@JsonRootName(value = "location")
public class Location {
    
  private String label;
  
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private Address address;
  
  // constructors, getters, setters ommited..
}


//// new file

public class Address{
  
  private String city;
  private String street;
  private String postCode;
  
}
```

This works 100% with Jackson/JSON. The embedded Address object will be unwrapped so that the JSON looks like this:

```css
{
  "label":"blah",
  "street":"Exchange Road",
  "city":"Stacktown"
  "postCode":"1337"
}
```

This works forth and back with Jackson.
JAXB on the other hand is able to parse (most of) the Jackson annotations, so that generally you wont have problems with using simple objects in both worlds. @JsonUnwrapped though sadly is NOT supported by JAXB, and strangely that (from my POV) quite simple usecase seems to be not reflectable with any JAXB annotation at all.

What happens is, that the generated schema contains the embedded Address object, without any attributes/elements.  Therefore the class generated by XJC will contain that Address object reference. And this ultimately leads to erroneous JSON from a app that will use the schema to generate objects...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification does not define an equivalent to Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped`.  For a long time we have offered that functionality in the [**EclipseLink MOXy**](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of JAXB via our `@XmlPath` extension.

```
  @XmlPath(".")
  private Address address;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: I know....Sadly enunciate relies on JAXB. Anyhow I simply accepted the fact, that I now have nested Address objects in my json. Doesn't hurt that much actually.